# Deletion from array of linked list structure in C from anywhere (start, middle, end)

Tags: arrays, c, struct, linked-list

I would like to know how to delete an element entirely from a structure. below is what I did but it seems to not delete correctly.

```
struct example
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    float price;
    
    struct example *next;
    struct example *previous;
};
struct example *head = NULL;
struct example *current = NULL;
struct example list[100];
int begin= 0, end=1;
```

To add an element:

```
   for(int i = begin; i<end; i++)
{
    printf("enter the id: \n");
    scanf("%d", &list[i].id);

    
    printf("enter the name: \n");
    scanf("%s", list[i].name);

    printf("enter the price: \n");
    scanf("%f", &list[i].price);


            if(i == 0)
            {
                list[i].previous = NULL;
                list[i].next = NULL;
                head = &list[i];
            }

            else
            {
                list[i].next = NULL;
                list[i].previous = &list[i-1];
                list[i-1].next = &list[i];
            }

        }


    printf("Added Element...\n");
    begin = begin+1;
    end = end+1;
```

this is the deletion:

```
void delete()
{

int temp, check;
if(head == NULL)
{

    printf("The structure is empty\n");
    exit(0);
}

printf("Enter the ID of delete: ");
scanf("%d",&temp);

int check = 0;


for(int i=0; i<end-1; i++)
{

    if(list[i].id == temp)
    {

        if(i==0 && head->next == NULL)
        {

            list[i].next = NULL;
            list[i].previous = NULL;
            head = NULL;

        }
        else if(i==0)
        {
            list[i].next = NULL;
            list[i+1].previous = NULL;
            head = &list[i+1];
        }
        else if(i == end-2) // I think issue is here
        {
            list[i].previous = NULL;
            list[i-1].next = NULL;
            end--;
            start--;

        }
        else
        {
            list[i].next = NULL;
            list[i].previous = NULL;
            list[i-1].next = &list[i+1];
            list[i+1].previous = &list[i-1];


        }

        check=1;

        break;
    }

}


if(check==0)
{
    printf("Item not found\n");
}

printf("Deletion success!\n");

}
```

To display:

```
if(head !=NULL)
    {
        current = head;
    printf("Display\n");

        while(current != NULL)
        {

            printf("------------------------------\n");
            printf("ID: %d\n", current->id);
            printf("Name: %s\n", current->name);
            printf("Price: %f\n", current->price);
            current = current->next;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("struct is Empty...\n");

    }
```

Please help fix the delete. When it outputs 8 elements and I remove the second or third, it will only display the first 2.
The issue could be in the if statements in the delete function for the connections.

```
Example display entering 5 elements and removing 3rd:

Before: 
ID: 1
Name: o 
Price: 2 
ID: 2 
Name: j 
Price: 3 
ID: 3 
Name: d
Price: 2 
ID: 4 
Name: z 
Price: 2 
ID: 5 
Name: s 
Price: 1 


After: 
ID: 1
Name: o 
Price: 2 
ID: 2 
Name: j 
Price: 3
```

Comment: 'It seems to not delete correctly', but what is the output? How do you run your code?

Comment: it outputs them but lets say if I add 9 items and remove the third, it will only display after the 1st and 2nd element

Comment: So, in the if statements that is where the deletion happens to remove the connections and rejoin them.

Comment: Step back from the source. Take a pen and paer and draw what you are doing. You will see what is wrong.

Comment: @ReadyToLearn Please [edit] your question and add all information from your comments to the question.

Comment: You can use an array to provide storage for your linked list nodes without any dynamic memory allocation.  That makes it relatively natural (but not without issues) to rely on the array nature when selecting an unused node for the next list element.  Beyond that, however, your list operations must rely on the *list* nature of your data structure, ignoring the array in which the nodes reside.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: So, @JohnBollinger, how can my code be fixed?

Comment: @ReadyToLearn, if and when I decide to answer that, you will know.

Comment: Any answers to my problem?